# Decoding base64 for a large file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, base64, nsxmlparser

I consuming Web-Services that streams a pdf file to my iOS device. I used SOAP message to interact with web-services and using `NSXMLParser:foundCharacters()` after the stream is complete and I want to get the content of pdf file from my streamed xml file which was created in first step. The data I get is encoded in base64 and I have the methods to decode the content back.For small file the easiest approach is reading/collect all content with `NSXMLParser:foundCharacters` from first streamed file and call the decoding base64 method when I get whole data from `parse:didEndElement` 
(the above approach works fine I tested for this case and I made the right pdf file out of it).

Now my question is what is the best approach(optimizing memory/speed) to read/decode/write to make the final pdf from a big streamed files.

Is there any code available or any thought to accomplish this in objective-C

Comment: Is it possible to ask the web-service you are talking to to provide you with a way to obtain the binary version of the file?  If you can, you will benefit from a smaller payload as well as avoiding the decode step.